# sed regex find & replace (awk solutions welcome)

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I'm working on a JSON file (for MongoDB) and need to convert a field name to Database Reference. I'm attempting to do it via sed (though I'm open to solutions using awk, etc), but I'm a complete noob with the tool and am struggling.

Input:

```
...
"FECTransID" : 4030720141206780377,
"CID" : "N00031103",
"CmteID" : "C00465971",
"RecipCode" : "RW",
"Amount" : 500,
....
```

Output needed:

```
...
"FECTransID" : 4030720141206780377,
"CID" : "N00031103",
"CmteID" : {
    "ref" : "Cmtes",
    "$id" : "C00278101",
    "$db" : "OpenSecrets"
},
"RecipCode" : "RW",
"Amount" : 500,
....
```

My `sed` command attempt is:

```
sed -r 's/\"CmteID\" \: \(\"[\w\d]\{9\}\",\)/\"CmteID\" : { \
                \"ref\" : \"Cmtes\", \
                \"$id\" : \1 \
                \"$db\" : \"OpenSecrets\" \
            }/' <IN_FILE >OUT_FILE
```

but I get this error when I run it:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 198: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should be using a JSON parser for this; it would be much safer. For example, if you have PHP this would be a 3-line script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `awk` approach:

```
awk '$1=="\"CmteID\"" {$3="{\n\t\"ref\" : \"Cmtes\",\
                            \n\t\"\$id\" : "$3"\
                            \n\t\"\$db\" : \"OpenSecrets\"\n},"}1' infile
```

**Explanation**

When the first field is matched `$1=="\"CmteID\""` we are changing the third field for the expected string, the only variable part is `CmteID` value , assigned in: `\n\t\"\$id\" : "$3"`

Line breaks added (escape char `\`) to improve the clarity of the code.

**Results**

```
"FECTransID" : 4030720141206780377,
"CID" : "N00031103",
"CmteID" : {
    "ref" : "Cmtes",                    
    "$id" : "C00465971",                    
    "$db" : "OpenSecrets"
},
"RecipCode" : "RW",
"Amount" : 500,
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '$1=="\"CmteID\""{print $1 ": {"; 
                         print "\t\"ref\" : \"Cmtes\","; 
                         print "\t\"$id\" : "$3;
                         print "\t\"$db\" : \"OpenSecrets\",";
                         print "},";
                         next}1' jsonfile

...
"FECTransID" : 4030720141206780377,
"CID" : "N00031103",
"CmteID": {
        "ref" : "Cmtes",
        "$id" : "C00465971",
        "$db" : "OpenSecrets",
},
"RecipCode" : "RW",
"Amount" : 500,
....
```

with some cleanup

```
$ awk -v NT="\n\t" 'function q(x) {return "\""x"\"";}; 
       $1==q("CmteID") {$3 = " {" 
                     NT q("ref") " : " q("Cmtes") "," 
                     NT q("$id") " : " $3 
                     NT q("$db") " : " q("OpenSecrets") 
                     ",\n},"}1' jsonfile
...
"FECTransID" : 4030720141206780377,
"CID" : "N00031103",
"CmteID" :  {
        "ref" : "Cmtes",
        "$id" : "C00465971",
        "$db" : "OpenSecrets",
},
"RecipCode" : "RW",
"Amount" : 500,
....
```

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. This problem is not like that, so this is not a job for sed.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=" : " }
$1 == "\"CmteID\"" {
    print $1, "{"
    print "   \"ref\"", "\"Cmtes\""
    print "   \"$id\"", $2
    print "   \"$db\"", "\"OpenSecrets\""
    $0 = "},"
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
...
TransID" : 4030720141206780377,
"CID" : "N00031103",
"CmteID" : {
   "ref" : "Cmtes"
   "$id" : "C00465971",
   "$db" : "OpenSecrets"
},
"RecipCode" : "RW",
"Amount" : 500,
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Many languages have built-in JSON parsers. PHP is one of them:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$infile = $argv[1];
$outfile = $argv[2];
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($infile));
$id = $data["CmteID"];
$data["CmteID"] = array("ref"=>"Cmtes", "\$id"=>$id, "\$db"=>"OpenSecrets");
file_put_contents($outfile, json_encode($data));
```

Untested but it should work. Make it executable and call `./myscript.php IN_FILE OUT_FILE`.

My main point being, JSON is not text and using text-replacement on it can lead to problems, just like other structured data formats like XML!

Comment: It doesn't seem to really do anything with the infile. The value for the `$id` field would need to be read from the infile (not hard-coded), and any line that isn't the `CmteID` field value need to be put into the outfile unaffected.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about the `$id` field in your question; and yes, all other lines are unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/"CmteID" : (.*)/"CmteID" : { \
            "ref" : "Cmtes", \
            "$id" : \1 \
            "$db" : "OpenSecrets" \
        },/' fileIn >fileOut
```

This was a case of over quoting. The parens grouping the `$id` had been quoted unneccessarily as the `-r` was inforce.